# JQueryUI Autocomplete: where is the selected value stored?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have succesfully set an autocomplete box on a page. However I have a timer which needs to fetch the selected value.

Where is this value stored? How can I retrieve it?

Thanks.

Comment: You tell us where it's stored. This would be done in your `focus:` or `select:` events of the plugin. Can we see the code for your `.autocomplete`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just grab the value from the target element (e.g. the input element to which you attached the autocomplete).